# Rolling up Migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-migrations

As I understand it the point of migrations is so you can revert the database back to a known state during the last stages of development.

Right now I'm still "fleshing" out my first Rails app and I'm wondering if its ok to roll up my migrations into bigger ones rather than dozens of changes.

Answer (score 4):

The point of migrations is that you basically have a log of database changes, so then other developers can know what changes have been made, or to make sure your production environment gets the same changes you made during development.

As for your question: sure. If you create a new model, and then after a few minutes decide "this column could just be a string instead of text", roll back your migration, and change the column and then migrate again. No need to create a new migration.

**Unless** you've already committed the previous migration to source control that may have been fetched by other developers, or you've already applied the migration on the production server. Then you should use a new migration.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum to rspeicher, I limit the constraint to whether a migration has been released, not to whether it has been made available to other developers. If it's still pre-release, then the development team can be informed of any need to run migrations for any updates of the master code repository by using post-fetch hooks for the SCM being used. This is true of any configuration management change, not just migrations. For example, changing an implementation of something in the initializers folder may have no effect on a running instance of script/server in development mode. This is a ultimately a necessary mechanism for most teams in most technologies as well as for some configurations of continuous integration. Or, you need excellent communications channels in the team to make sure that everyone knows that a configuration change and restart is necessary.